# Is it possible to relocate the camera to the binded group without double-tap?

Tags: starcraft-2, keyboard

I'm looking for an alternative to double-click in StarCraft 2. I would like a number key (or a custom key) to relocate the camera to the associated numbered group with just a single-click. Is it possible?

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Do you actually click on the button in the UI or double-tap the key on your keyboard?

Comment: I don't think there is a faster way than pressing your group's key twice.

Comment: @F.S. By 'double-click' I meant pressing a key twice (on the keyboard) not UI mouse-click of course =)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only three methods I am aware of are

- Hit the number and then mouse-click at the unit portrait to center your screen over the selected unit/building
- Bind your control group keys to 2 hotkeys (Primary and Alternative hotkey) and hit both after each other
- Hit the hotkey for `Center on Current selection` (Ctrl+F by default)

Nevertheless, all ways would need 2 clicks or key presses anyway.
But I think simple double-tapping is the fastest way to move your screen to a control group. Also you don't want your screen to move every time but only check what your group is doing, e.g. building or research progress.

Answer (score 1):

In starcraft2 there are numerous ways to move your mouse:

- Double-Tap Stored Unit Selection Key
- Store Screen location (Shift + F5 saves - F5 then jumps to that location)
- Select Unit and click Portrait in bottom right.

None will center your screen above a Unit without at least two key presses.
(Unless you own a programmable Keyboard where you could define macros that double-tap the key for you)

Answer (score 0):

It's indeed impossible afaik to bind to a single button. However, if you bind 'center on selection' to §, or an equally accessible button, you can recall your control group and then immediately press § as a single action, so you don't have to use the clumsy double-tap. Almost as good as a single button.